# Can WebAPI change output just before response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a WebAPI for an external mobile company ( all I do is exposing  services).

Right now , our DB uses *non-encrypted* values for columns like :

- ObjectID
- PolicyID
- etc..

But now , when we expose it , and  I need to *encrypt* values. ( only server can decrypt values , the mobile company doesn't care about the actual values).

I don't want to start digest *every* Stored Procedure response manually and replace values with encrypted ones. ( don't forget that our internal server does *not* uses encrypted values - it uses data regularly).

**OK** Here's a live example :

I have this controller code :

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("test2")]
public HttpResponseMessage test2(int id)
{
   var Data = GetDataFromSource_1();
            // or from GetDataFromSource_2(); 
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Data);
}
```

Where `GetDataFromSource_1` is via dynamic list (just to simulate  a source)

```
public IEnumerable GetDataFromSource_1()
{
    List<dynamic> lst = new List<dynamic>();
    lst.Add(new
    {
        objId = 1,
        myOtherColumn = 5
    });
    lst.Add(new
    {
        objId = 2,
        myOtherColumn = 8
    });
    return lst;
}
```

And

`GetDataFromSource_2` is via DataTable ( just to simulate another source)

```
public DataTable GetDataFromSource_2()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("myTable");
    dt.Columns.Add("objId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("myOtherColumn", typeof(int));
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["objId"] = 1;
    row["myOtherColumn"] = 5;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["objId"] = 2;
    row["myOtherColumn"] = 8;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    return dt;
}
```

Both yields this json response:

> {"Result":{"Success":true,"Message":""},"Data":[{"objId":1,"myOtherColumn":5},{"objId":2,"myOtherColumn":8}]}

**Question**

How (and where) can I scan the content of the response ( which is going to be sent) and replace for every column in ( and **only** for them) :

- ObjectID
- PolicyID
- etc..

to an **encrypted** value ?

For example :

I Would like the output to be :

```
{
    "Result": {
        "Success": true,
        "Message": ""
    },
    "Data": [{
        "objId": "XXX_the_encrypted_valueXXX",
        "myOtherColumn": 5
    }, {
        "objId": "XXX_the_encrypted_valueXXX":  ,
        "myOtherColumn": 8
    }]
}
```

(where `"XXX_the_encrypted_valueXXX"` is an encrypted value of the old value.)

NB it's assumable that I have `Utils.Encrypt(string st)` method.

Also , we dont have entities so i can not decorate an entity . I need to plugin when the json is created

Comment: Are the encrypted variables the same for all metohd calls? Or do they vary?

Comment: @yuval , in every response no matter what , if the response result contain a column named :( look up ), convert its value to encrypted one

Comment: Are those column names identical in all queries or do they vary? How do you know which column name needs to encrypted?

Comment: @yuval , if the column names in ("objectid","policyid") then convert its value

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I see your point. edited the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a custom `DelegatingHandler` by deriving it and supplying your own implementation and register it your `config.MessageHandlers`.

So we need a handler and a recursive method which iterates the entire JSON. We'll use the answer provided in [Searching for a specific JToken by name in a JObject hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645501/searching-for-a-specific-jtoken-by-name-in-a-jobject-heirarchy):

```
private static void FindTokens(JToken containerToken, string name, List<JToken> matches)
{
    if (containerToken.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        foreach (JProperty child in containerToken.Children<JProperty>())
        {
            if (child.Name == name)
            {
                matches.Add(child.Value);
            }
            FindTokens(child.Value, name, matches);
        }
    }
    else if (containerToken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        foreach (JToken child in containerToken.Children())
        {
            FindTokens(child, name, matches);
        }
    }
}
```

And the complete handler will look as following:

```
public class JsonEncrypterHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        var returnedJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(returnedJson);

        List<JToken> objIdTokens = new List<JToken>();
        List<JToken> policyIdTokens = new List<JToken>();

        FindTokens(jObj, "objid", objIdTokens);
        FindTokens(jObj, "policyid", policyIdTokens);

        foreach (JValue objId in objIdTokens)
        {
            objId.Value = Utils.Encrypt(objIdValue);
        }

        foreach (JValue policyId in policyIdTokens)
        {
            policyId.Value = Utils.Encrypt(policyIdTokens);
        }

        response.Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObj);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: will it do it recursivly ?

Comment: `Data` can contain anything. as my question states : _How can I scan the content of the response ( which is going to be sent) and replace **for every column in ( and only for them)**_

Comment: That's why i asked if the properties are constant. Meaning, you want to change `objId` and `policyId` only. I'll ask again. Do you know which properties you want to encrypt?

Comment: And I've answered :-) , **only** those 2 columns should be changed , but they can appear in a different hierarchy. it's just like you open this json in notepad , and press "search and replace" and modify all values for "objId" and "policyId" columns

Comment: Right, well, we're iterating the entire `Data` property, which is a `JArray`. So it'll iterate the whole array. Is it going to appear in places other than your `Data` array? If the entire hierarchy can have them, i'll need to create a more general algorithm that looks for those properties.

Comment: No it's not. but `data ` is not always an array . it can be object. consider this demo json  http://i.stack.imgur.com/FJoSJ.jpg , objId and policyId can appear anywhere in this file

Comment: Can you add a full complex JSON to your question?

Comment: I need something real to work with. Make sure it contains the `objId` field and the others you want.

Comment: here it is : http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0bWL.jpg  those 1,2,3 values should be changed. here is the json :  http://jsbin.com/yuniqi/2/edit?html

Comment: @RoyiNamir See my modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should decorate the encrypted properties with an `Attribute`:

```
[JsonEncryptValue]
public Guid ObjectID {get;set;}
```

And then add a `JsonConverter` that will handle only properties that have a `JsonEncryptValue` attribute on them.
You can re-write their value easily.

And then all you need to do is add your `JsonConverter` to the `JsonSerializer` in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file:

```
    JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    JsonSerializerSettings jSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
    };

    jSettings.Converters.Add(new EncryptionJsonConverter());
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jSettings;
```

Comment: I dont have properties . There is no Entities in our project so i have nothing to decorate

Comment: Ohh... You can always create ugly workarounds like creating an httpmodule that does the replacement. I guess there is a better practice though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create customer attribute. Decorate all your action or controller with that attribute.

In that on you have to read result and deserialize back to Json object or .net object.

Following link will help you on that.

http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/