# How do I assign parameter values to a string using c#

Tags: c#, json, rest, deserialization, attask

I'm working on an implementation of workfront api and my application. This is suppose to be simple. Perhaps my code will explain better.

```
JToken tasks = client.Search(ObjCode.TASK, new { fields = "ID, extRefID, assignedTo:name" });
taskid = c.Value<string>("ID");
workItem = c.Value<string>("extRefID");
taskAssgTo = c.Value<string>("assignedTo:name");
```

Now, taskid and workItem return values correctly. I'm having trouble understanding why taskAssgTo will always return null. When debuggin, I can clearly see that assignedTo:name has correct values, but for some reason I will not assign it to taskAssgTo. (taskAssgTo is a string variable).

This is how it looks when retrieving the data using REST:

```
{
  "ID": "4c78285f00000908ea8cfd66e084939f",
  "extRefId": "4561",
  "assignedTo": {
    "ID": "4c78285f00000908ea8cfd66e084215a",
    "name": "Admin User"
  } 
}
```

Please I would appreciate an explanation and a possible solution to this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Blast_dan has the correct answer below. What is being returned is basically a complex object and assignedTo has a property "name". To get to the value you would use assignedTo.name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any documentation that says that you can access child values in the manner you are trying to access them.

I would try using dot notation instead, such as

```
taskAssgTo = c.Value<string>("assignedTo.name");
```

or following the link below to see how to navigate a JObject hierarchy

[Searching for a specific JToken by name in a JObject hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645501/searching-for-a-specific-jtoken-by-name-in-a-jobject-hierarchy)

Comment: Thank you! 
    tasks.SelectToken("data[0].assignedTo.name").ToString();
works better. Thanks for showing me how the toke.path works. I'm really new at working with json and workfront api, and any help is greatly appreciated.