# Parsing out a portion of a JSON file and seeing the data

Tags: json, f#, f#-interactive, f#-data

I found this [F# JSON parsing - How to get property using complex path (consisting of several propery names)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365041/f-json-parsing-how-to-get-property-using-complex-path-consisting-of-several) (I shortened the file string). I am wondering how to show the actual data from the json file in the FSI window?

```
let soilTest = JsonValue.Load("c:\\,,,soiltest.json")
let query soilTest=
    let node = JObject.Parse soilTest
    node.SelectToken "person[0].name" |> string
```

Here is the beginning of the json file:

```
 {
      "person": [
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "date": "December 1, 2015",
    .....
```

I looked at the link that Mark Seemann provided to see how to get the data out of the json file and be shown in the console.
 
However when putting

```
Console.WriteLine(name)
```

I get this warning:

```
 warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'string'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.

val query : soilTest:string -> unit
```

Tried |>ignore at the end of console.writeline and I get val query : soulTest:string -> unit

How do you do a let statement from this point to bind the data to it?

Comment: First, it's possible that `query` is not a reserved word, but I would still avoid binding to it. Just use `qry`. What is `name` bound to? In the last line of your function you might want to say `let name = node.SelectToken "person[0].name" |> string` then on the next line say `Console.WriteLine(name) |> ignore`.  But generally you should be able to do pretty much anything with Newtonsoft.JSON...and/or the json provider.

Comment: When i alter or remove query I get this error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    string    
but here has type
>     JsonValue   .

Comment: how do you alter/remove the query? can you show the whole code, including whatever open statements you have, what you execute and the error. Can you come by http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f to avoid going back and forth in the comments

Comment: btw, you can avoid the whole `JObject.Parse` and access the name directly: `soilTest.["person"].[0].["name"]  |> string`.

Comment: Simpler code is better thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`soilTest` is a of type `JsonValue` but you're trying to parse it as `string`, hence the error. Please adjust the path for your environment, otherwise this works for me:

```
let soilTest = JsonValue.Load(@"c:\tmp\test.json")
let qry (soilTest:JsonValue) = 
    let data = JObject.Parse (soilTest.ToString()) 
    data.SelectToken "person[0].name" |> string

qry soilTest
//val it : string = "John Doe"
```

There might be better ways to work with. Json and xml are the bane of my existence...
**Edit:** e.g. you can access the properties directly, like this:

```
let soilTest = JsonValue.Load(@"c:\tmp\test.json")  
soilTest.["person"].[0].["name"].AsString()
//val it : string = "John Doe"
```