# Deserialize both string and array of strings for the same field

Tags: c#, json

I have the use case where I need to deserialize json into an object. The json is as follows

```
{
    "additionalAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "type",
            "value": "action"
        },
        {
            "name": "pages",
            "value": [                
                "34",
                "39",
                "43"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "chapters",
            "value": [                
                "The dawn of time",
                "The end of the world"
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

The difficult part is that **value** is either a string or an array of strings. The resulting object should have an array of strings, even if there is only one string in it.

How can I do this with json.net? The deserializer complains that the first value is not an array of strings.

I cannot change the source json.

Many thanks
Maarten

Comment: With a case like this, it seems like it would be optimal to just use a `JObject` instead of trying to define complex contracts in C#'s typing system. Performance hit would be negligible compared to the complexity of trying to add custom logic to serialization/deserialization

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118012/check-jobject-contains-an-array?rq=1 That gives you what you need

Comment: Add `[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<string>))]` to your `value` property as shown in [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182).

Answer (score -1):

String and string arrays both inherit from `object`. So your model can look like this

```
public class AdditionalAttribute
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would have to unbox the object to one of the two types.

Another option is to define value as partial struct with implicit operators, like below

```
public partial class AdditionalAttribute
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }
}

public partial struct Value
{
    public string _value;
    public List<string> _valueArray;

    public static implicit operator Value(string value) => new Value { _value = value};
    public static implicit operator Value(List<string> valueArray) => new Value { _valueArray= valueArray};
}
```

Comment: This does not work with the string and List<string>. Your comment about using only object / dynamic as the type works but not with type Value.

Comment: Using `object` will not work. .NET JSON serialize deserializes to `JsonElement` whenever it sees `object`. Just as `Json.Net` would deserialize this to `JObject`/`JArray`.