# Deserialize JSON string in to multiple C# objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON string in below format for which I want to deserialize it into C# List. But the record number "1","2","3" (**it can be upto 1,2,3...n depends on the json response each time**) in JSON restricting me to deserialize it into C# object using Newtonsoft.Json

```
{
"1":{
      "UID":"1",
      "LICENCENO":"licenseno",
      "NAME":"ABC"
    },
"2":{
      "UID":"2",
      "LICENCENO":"licenseno",
      "NAME":"PQR"
    },
"3":{
      "UID":"3",
      "LICENCENO":"licenseno",
      "NAME":"XYZ"      
    }
}
```

I am using below code for deserialization

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DriverMaster>>(json);
```

I have DriverMaster class created as-

```
public class DriverMaster
{
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string LICENCENO { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization line giving unhandled exception, I know I am doing it in wrong way, because DriverMaster json object cannot be extracted into c# directly without doing *something* to record number **1,2,3...n** in c#. Can anyone please help me to sort it out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, DriverMaster>>(json)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Solution.**
>   Change your code to use...
>
> ```
> var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, DriverMaster>>(json);
> ```

---

**Explaination**

The type is not the same... The `List<DriverMaster>`type will convert to JSON like so...

```
{
    "1":
    {
        "DriverMaster": {
            "UID":"1",
            "LICENCENO":"licenseno",
            "NAME":"ABC"
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't match what you showed in your question...

The type that you are looking for is actually `Dictionary<int, DriverMaster>`, which is a key/value pair which will output a JSON string like so

```
{
    "1": { ... },
    "2": { ... },
    "3": { ... }
}
```

In order to fix that, you need to use the `Dictionary<int, DriverMaster>` type instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
public class DriverMaster
{
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string LICENCENO { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string,JToken> Data {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

If you want to have result as List, you can parse the result as.

```
var list = new List<DriverMaster>();
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, JToken> token in result.Data)
{
    list.Add(token.Value.ToObject<DriverMaster>());
}
```

That would give you the desired result as

```
1 licenseno ABC 
2 licenseno PQR 
3 licenseno XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

For these types of things I like to use the often overlooked feature of [`JToken.SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm). This function allows you to select tokens within a json string and permits the use of wildcards.

Here's some code that will deserialize your sample by selecting past the 1,2,3...N in the json:

```
public static IEnumerable<DriverMaster> Deserialize(string json)
{
    return JToken.Parse(json).SelectTokens("*")
        .Select(jToken => jToken.ToObject<DriverMaster>());
}
```

The `*` basically says to select all tokens after the root, so it's selecting the values associated with 1, 2, 3.. etc... Here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29782523/1582922) SO answer that shows a more complicated usage of the `SelectTokens` method.