# c# parsing azure policy rule json to make a tree

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-policy

I wanted to parse the JSON with Newtonsoft.Json.Linq into to a tree format by going to each root level.

The actual problem i am facing is the content inside the allOf is not getting printed and its getting InvalidCast exception in JObject. I need help to print all the parent and child elements in the console application.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Audit if Key Vault has no virtual network rules",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "Audits Key Vault vaults if they do not have virtual network service endpoints set up. More information on virtual network service endpoints in Key Vault is available here: _https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview-vnet-service-endpoints",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "Key Vault",
      "createdBy": "",
      "createdOn": "",
      "updatedBy": "",
      "updatedOn": ""
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.virtualNetworkRules[*].id",
                "exists": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.virtualNetworkRules[*].id",
                "notLike": "*"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.defaultAction",
                "equals": "Allow"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/wkpolicydef",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "xyz"
}
```

And my code:

```
static JmesPath jmes = new JmesPath();
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string policyStr = "JSON GIVEN IN THE DESCRIPTION";
        string str = jmes.Transform(policyStr, "properties.policyRule.if");
        Convert(str);
    }

    public static void Convert(string json)
    {
        dynamic myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        PrintObject(myObj, 0);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void PrintObject(JToken token, int depth)
    {
        if (token is JProperty)
        {
            var jProp = (JProperty)token;
            var spacer = string.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, depth).Select(_ => "\t"));
            var val = jProp.Value is JValue ? ((JValue)jProp.Value).Value : "-";

            Console.WriteLine($"{spacer}{jProp.Name}  -> {val}");


            foreach (var child in jProp.Children())
            {
                PrintObject(child, depth + 1);
            }
        }
        else if (token is JObject)
        {
            foreach (var child in ((JObject)token).Children())
            {
                PrintObject(child, depth + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have installed JMESPath.Net NuGet package.  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LVxr2O).

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: @Stijn I needed to form a tree in c# but not able to do it till the child level

i have followed the below link but its not accessing all the elements its excluding few elements

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837283/c-sharp-parsing-relaxed-json-to-make-a-tree

Comment: Please add the code that you use to form the tree. It's not possible to tell you what part of your code is wrong without seeing it.

Comment: @Stijn i have added the code for reference

Comment: @dbc i have added the code for reference

Comment: @KailashP - your code doesn't compile, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/jOUtJe: *Compilation error (line 24, col 10): The type or namespace name 'JmesPath' could not be found*.  Can you share the JSON string being passed into `Convert`?

Comment: However this may help: [How to do recursive descent of json using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16208023).

Comment: @dbc i have installed JMESPath.Net NuGet package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that, in `PrintObject(JToken token, int depth)`, you do not consider the case of the incoming `token` being a [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm):

```
if (token is JProperty)
{
}
else if (token is JObject)
{
}
// Else JArray, JConstructor, ... ?
```

Since the value of `"allOf"` is an array, your code does nothing:

```json
{
  "allOf": [ /* Contents omitted */ ]
}
```

A minimal fix would be to check for [`JContainer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer.htm) instead of `JObject`, however, this does not handle the case of an array containing primitive values, and so cannot be considered a proper fix.  (Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TOBpe1).)

Instead, in your recursive code you need to handle all possible subclasses of `JContainer` including `JObject`, `JArray`, `JProperty` and (maybe) `JConstructor`.  However, the inconsistency between `JObject`, which has two levels of hierarchy, and `JArray` which has only one, can make writing such recursive code annoying.

One possible solution to processing arrays and objects in a cleaner manner would be to hide the existence of `JProperty` entirely and represent that objects are containers whose children are indexed by name while arrays are containers whose children are indexed by integers.  The following extension method does this job:

```
public interface IJTokenWorker
{
    bool ProcessToken<TConvertible>(JContainer parent, TConvertible index, JToken current, int depth) where TConvertible : IConvertible;
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void WalkTokens(this JToken root, IJTokenWorker worker, bool includeSelf = false)
    {
        if (worker == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        DoWalkTokens<int>(null, -1, root, worker, 0, includeSelf);
    }

    static void DoWalkTokens<TConvertible>(JContainer parent, TConvertible index, JToken current, IJTokenWorker worker, int depth, bool includeSelf) where TConvertible : IConvertible
    {
        if (current == null)
            return;
        if (includeSelf)
        {
            if (!worker.ProcessToken(parent, index, current, depth))
                return;
        }
        var currentAsContainer = current as JContainer;
        if (currentAsContainer != null)
        {
            IList<JToken> currentAsList = currentAsContainer; // JContainer implements IList<JToken> explicitly
            for (int i = 0; i < currentAsList.Count; i++)
            {
                var child = currentAsList[i];
                if (child is JProperty)
                {
                    DoWalkTokens(currentAsContainer, ((JProperty)child).Name, ((JProperty)child).Value, worker, depth+1, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    DoWalkTokens(currentAsContainer, i, child, worker, depth+1, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your `Convert()` method now becomes:

```
class JTokenPrinter : IJTokenWorker
{
    public bool ProcessToken<TConvertible>(JContainer parent, TConvertible index, JToken current, int depth) where TConvertible : IConvertible
    {
        var spacer = new String('\t', depth);
        string name;
        string val;

        if (parent != null && index is int)
            name = string.Format("[{0}]", index);
        else if (parent != null && index != null)
            name = index.ToString();
        else 
            name = "";

        if (current is JValue)
            val = ((JValue)current).ToString();
        else if (current is JConstructor)
            val = "new " + ((JConstructor)current).Name;
        else
            val = "-";

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}   -> {2}", spacer, name, val));
        return true;
    }
}

public static void Convert(string json)
{
    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
    root.WalkTokens(new JTokenPrinter());
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TOBpe1), which outputs:

```
allOf   -> -
    [0]   -> -
        field   -> type
        equals   -> Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults
    [1]   -> -
        anyOf   -> -
            [0]   -> -
                field   -> Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.virtualNetworkRules[*].id
                exists   -> false
            [1]   -> -
                field   -> Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.virtualNetworkRules[*].id
                notLike   -> *
            [2]   -> -
                field   -> Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/networkAcls.defaultAction
                equals   -> Allow
```

Related:

- *[How to do recursive descent of json using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16181298/3744182)*
- *[How to recursively populate a TreeView with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39673815/3744182)*
- *[Iterate over a json input and create the treeview like hierarchy based on the "keys" taking account of the children "keys"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56383331/3744182)*